# Minimizing matrix norms with scipy.minimize

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, minimize

I am trying to minimize `(A_m-B*C_m)**2` where A is fixed matrix and B and C are variable matrices. The matrices have shapes (3,3,512,512), (3,3,512,1), and (1,1,512,512), respectively.

Any advice on where I am going wrong, or any advice in general on how to perform this optimization is appreciated.

**Code**

```
# objective function
def f(params, A):
    total = 0
    B, C = params
    for k in range(0,512):
        for m in range(0,512):
            for n in range(0,9):
                total += (A[k*m*n] - B[m*n] * C[k*m])**2
    print(total)
    return total

# create matrices
A = np.random.rand(3,3,512,512)
B = np.random.rand(3,3,512,1)
C = np.random.rand(1,1,512,512)

# flatten into 1d vectors
A = A.ravel()
B = B.ravel()
C = C.ravel()

# perform minimization
x = [B, C]
result = optimize.minimize(f, x, args=(A))
```

**Output** I get numbers for 'total' for a few iterations, and then it crashes:

```
407783.32968906895
407783.3247324555
407783.3244573258
407783.32968906895
2988640.705408569
2988640.705408569
2988640.797336188
2988640.7918476323
358476.57749339886
358476.57749339886
358476.57633670256
358476.5758499606
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minimize.py", line 148, in <module>
result = optimize.minimize(f, x, args=(A))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 481, in minimize
return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 994, in _minimize_bfgs
rhok = 1.0 / (numpy.dot(yk, sk))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4608,) (262144,)
```

Comment: Those are not matrices, but multi dim arrays. Those are not opt-iterations but numerical differentiation steps (imho), so that not a single opt-it is happening as expected. Look at x and what x becomes. X being 1d/a vector is a core assumption of minimize. You can unpack, reshape in your funcs later, but from the outside: 1d! Add prints of those shapes/dimensions involved for debugging. Total returned needs to be a scalar.

Comment: You want to optimize over B.size + C.size > 260000 variables ??